# Why does this work but the other one fails( Linq To Xml)

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I tried this simple query on LinqPad and scratched by head as to why the second query works but the first one just does not alter the list(**descen**).

- How do i make it work. I use this code to clone and modify xml attribute,value

#### Fails

```
var doc = XElement.Parse("<Root><Descendants>Welcome</Descendants><Descendants>Stack</Descendants><Descendants>Overflow</Descendants></Root>");
var descen = (from des in doc.Descendants("Descendants") select new XElement(des));
foreach (var desc in descen)
{
    desc.Value += DateTime.UtcNow;
}
descen.Dump();
doc.Dump();
```

#### Works

```
var doc = XElement.Parse("<Root><Descendants>Welcome</Descendants><Descendants>Stack</Descendants><Descendants>Overflow</Descendants></Root>");
var descen = (from des in doc.Descendants("Descendants") select new XElement(des));
foreach (var desc in doc.Descendants("Descendants"))
{
    desc.Value += DateTime.UtcNow;
}
descen.Dump();
doc.Dump();
```

#### Stall's my PC ?? WTH

```
var doc = XElement.Parse("<Root><Descendants>Welcome</Descendants><Descendants>Stack</Descendants><Descendants>Overflow</Descendants></Root>");
var descen = (from des in doc.Descendants("Descendants") select des);
foreach (var desc in descen)
{
    desc.Value += DateTime.UtcNow;
}
var instance = from t in descen select new XElement(t);
doc.Elements("Descendants").LastOrDefault().AddAfterSelf(instance);
descen.Dump();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first query, `descen` is a projection from existing elements to *new* elements. It's lazily evaluated - each time you iterate over it, it will create new elements.

In the first case, you iterate over `descen`, and modify the new elements as you go. However, those modified elements are effectively thrown away very soon after they're created - they're not part of the original document.

In the second case, you modify the elements in the *original* document, so when you iterate over `descen`, it will create a copy of the *modified* elements, and displays those.

EDIT: If you want to change `descen` but *not* the original document, you can just add `ToList()` at the end of the initialization part of `descen`. For example:

```
var descen = (from des in doc.Descendants("Descendants")
              select new XElement(des)).ToList();
```

Or, more readably IMO:

```
var descen = doc.Descendants("Descendants")
                .Select(x => new XElement(x))
                .ToList();
```

The reason your final code hangs is that as `AddAfterSelf` iterates over `instance`, it's adding elements... but those elements are then part of the document, which means they're part of the `descen` query, which means they're part of the `instance` query... so iterating over `instance` will never complete.

Comment: Hi jon, Is it possible to persist the change in *descen* `IEnumerable<XElement>` inside the for each loop if not any other ways? because if this isn't possible how does one clone nodes to be changed and added to original document

Comment: Jon i added `Stall's my PC ?? WTH` section, now i am doing something seriously wrong. Could you explain it to me

Comment: @Deeptechtons you are alterating the collection that descen iterates over and since instance iterates over descen you are indirectly changing the collection instance iterates over. AddAfterSelf will have to iterate over instance and each time a new element is inserted into doc then that becomes an element instance (might) have to iterate over